# T-SQL. GroupBy Truncated DATETIME and order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table of Orders like:

```
Order
=========
Date (DATETIME)
Price (INT)
```

And I would like to know how much money we earned per every month and output should look like:

```
January-2018 : 100 
February-2018: 200
...
January-2019: 300
...
```

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(MONTH , DATEADD(M, t.MDate , -1 ) ) + '-' + CAST(t.YDate as NVARCHAR(20)),
    SUM(Price)
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    DATEPART(YYYY, o.Date) as YDate,
    DATEPART(MM, o.Date) as MDate,  
    Price
FROM [Order] o
) t
GROUP BY t.YDate, t.MDate
ORDER BY t.YDate, t.MDate
```

Is it ok or may be there is a better approach ?

Comment: You can do this by replacing t.mdate and t.ydate with your datepart statements. This will allow you to lose the subquery. You’d then have to group by your entire datename concatenation statement. Sorry... wrote this via mobile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format()` is the way to go.  I would recommend:

```
select format(o.date, 'MMMM-yyyy') as Monthyear,    
       sum(o.price) as total 
from orders o
group by format(datenew, 'MMMM-yyyy')
order by min(o.date)
```

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . And what is the issue?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm intrigued by "order by min(...) " it seems very unclear for me and I'd expect simply "order by  o.Date" - but T-SQL doesn't allow this. Do I undestand correctly that "order by min" does the same thing as "order by" but I just have to use aggregate function "min" because of group by ?  I may also use "order by max"  - it will not affect the result ?

Comment: Just the output is in a one column form splitting fields with a colon

Comment: @user149691 . . . The `order by min(date)` does exactly what the code says.  Each "group" in the data is ordered by its minimum date -- and that is the ordering that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have checked both versions (min and max) with my data - nothing has changed. Only "ASC" and "DESC" rule output rows order, not min or max.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just with this?

```
with Orders as (
  select convert(date,'2018-01-15') as [date], 10 as Price union all
  select convert(date,'2018-01-20'), 20 union all
  select convert(date,'2018-01-30'), 30 union all
  select convert(date,'2018-02-15'), 20 union all
  select convert(date,'2018-03-15'), 40 union all
  select convert(date,'2018-03-20'), 50

)
select 
  datename(month,o.Date) + '-' + datename(year,o.Date) + ': ' + 
  convert(varchar(max),SUM(Price))
FROM [Orders] o
group by datename(month,o.Date) + '-' + datename(year,o.Date)
order by 1 desc
```

I don't get well why are you removing one month in your query, I am not doing it. You can test it here: https://rextester.com/GRKK80105

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sql server 2012 or + , you can make use of format function as well.

```
select cast('2018-02-23 15:34:09.390' as datetime)  as datenew, 100 as price  into #temp union all 
select cast('2018-02-24 15:34:09.390' as datetime)  as datenew, 300 as price   union all 
select cast('2018-03-10 15:34:09.390' as datetime)  as datenew, 500 as price   union all 
select cast('2018-03-11 15:34:09.390' as datetime)  as datenew, 700 as price   union all 
select cast('2019-02-23 15:34:09.390' as datetime)  as datenew, 900 as price   union all 
select cast('2019-02-23 15:34:09.390' as datetime)  as datenew,  1500 as price    

select Monthyear,  total  from  ( 
select format(datenew, 'MMMM-yyyy') Monthyear, format(datenew, 'yyyyMM')  NumMMYY ,sum(price) total from #temp 
group by format(datenew, 'MMMM-yyyy') , format(datenew, 'yyyyMM') ) test 
order by NumMMYY
```

Since format will convert it to nvarchar, I had to create one more column in the subquery to order it properly. If you don't mind one more column you don't have to use subquery,  and you can order it with another column. I could not find any other way (except for case statement which is not a very good idea)  to do it in the same select

```
Output: 
 Monthyear      Total
 February-2018  400
 March-2018     1200
 February-2019  2400
```